# Are there complete rankings for current TV shows in North America?

Tags: scheduling

Are there complete rankings for current TV shows in North America? I already tried:

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/imdbpicks/monthly-tv-picks/?ref_=nv_tvv_picks_1). It doesn't enable filtering of results, in my case to shows that are currently broadcast.

[Metacritic](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/tv/release-date/returning-series/metascore). But for 'Returning Series', it neglects some TV shows, like the TNT show 'The Last Ship' is neglected and the ABC or Global TV show 'Rookie Blue.'

[Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/top-tv/). It doesn't list all returning shows.

Answer (score 1):

I think the site [tvseriesfinale.com](http://tvseriesfinale.com) will have what you want. In spite of its name, it is NOT solely about the finales of series, but deals in ratings and analysis of television in general. It also ranks shows and projects cancellation based on collected metrics. It presents ratings by network, including networks outside the "Big Three", and is kept updated virtually every day with early ratings of the previous night. It distributes also via RSS feed, if that is your taste.

Disclaimer: I am NOT affiliated with the site in any way, beyond as an interested reader.